# Select query using row values as column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a dataset using SQL Server.

I have following tables

- `Product` - id, name
- `ProductIngredient` - id,productId,ingredientId
- `Ingredient` - id, name
- `Allergens` - id, name

Here is the diagram and expected output that I need

[image: database tables]

Here is what I have tried

```
select distinct 
    p.*, 
    if(i.name = 'Gluten'  ,'No' ,'Yes') As Milk, 
    if(i.name = 'Nut'  ,'No' ,'Yes') As Butter, 
    if(i.name = 'Dairy'  ,'No' ,'Yes') As Salt 
from 
    product p, ingredient i, productingredient pi  
where 
    pi.productID = p.id 
    and i.id = pi.productid;
```

But the problem is it is returning me erroneous results.I am banging my head on this for past two days.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list. You show some code, we (maybe) try help fix it. We're not here to write it for you.

Comment: We don't do your homework for you. Give it a try. If you can't get it to work, post what you have done and what problems you are having and we will try to help you.

Comment: @MarcB sorry.. yea I tried different things

Comment: @C4CodeE4Exe like what?

Comment: @RobertColumbia http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/239326/3/0

Comment: Draw a clearer diagram and you'll see what's going on.  First, make it clear whether you want a straightforward join, or a parts explosion, or something in between.  It isn't altogether clear to me.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner I have updated the diagram.I just need simple joins and I am not able to show everything in one row

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: make a join over all five tables, select only distinct combinations of product and allegen names and use SQL Server style of pivoting tables `select ... from ... pivot ...`